# Bash replace first 4 characters after tail -f

Tags: bash, wildcard, cut, tail

I have a log-file as .txt where I want the first four characters to be replaced by `****` or `XXXX` to anonymize the data.

I am running the following command:

```
tail -f file.txt
```

I know I can cut the first characters the following way:

```
tail -f file.txt | cut -c4-
```

But I would then like to insert four wildcard characters.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 1234567890 | sed 's/..../****/'
```

Output:

```
****567890
```

Answer (score 0):

To tail the file continuously with the first four characters anonymized, you can use the following command:

```
tail -f file.txt | sed 's/^..../****/'
```

If you have a file that's done being written to and you want to anonymize all the data in it at once, you can use sed as follows:

```
sed -i 's/^..../****/g' 58486880.txt
```

Note that this second command works with GNU/Linux sed, but not BSD/MacOS sed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the question and title do not match, to replace the last four you have to use `$` as such:

```
tail -f tmp.txt | sed 's/.\{4\}$/****/'
```

To test:

```
 while true; do cat <(seq 1 10 | tr -d '\n') <(echo) >> tmp.txt; sleep 1; done
```

This produces:

```
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
1234567****
```